# How can We import the data from Table-valued functions to Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is there any way by which we can import the data from table-valued fuction to Azure SQL Database, I cant find any document or any way in which I can achive this.

Comment: Perhaps you can give an example?  In general, you should be able to do INSERT INTO localtable SELECT * from TVF(…);  If there's more nuance to the question, please edit and I am sure I or others will be happy to try to get you unblocked

Comment: I want to migrate the table valued functions which are onpremise to my Azure SQL Database. How can this be done?

Comment: You can use SSDT to export the schema from SQL Server and then import it to SQL Azure.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017  or you can do sp_helptext on the tvf to get the definition and replay a single TVF DDL on SQL Azure.  This would work for T-SQL TVFs.  CLR TVFs are not currently supported in SQL Azure (but they are on SQL Azure Managed Instances)

Comment: How can I build a pipeline to do daily sync of table valued function

Comment: a Table-valued function is a DDL command.  Once you move it, it is moved.  If you are unwilling to share a concrete example of what you want to do, I can't help you.

Comment: Well there is something called streamline db which one of our customer is using and all the data is in TVF Form, the customer wants to copy daily data to Azure SQL Database, so I am in search of something which can copy the data on daily basis to azure sql database.

Comment: The data in a TVF in SQL is not persistent as such, usually.  In any event, if you want to sync data from a SQL Server to SQL Azure, I suggest you look into something like Data Sync as a tool to help with that:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync

Comment: Data dync does not support the move of TVF I belive it only supports sync of the tables.

Comment: There is no data in the TVF, as I said, so I can't really help you move it.  If you are using a CLR TVF to read data from some other place into SQL Server, then I suggest you write that to a table in SQL Server and then use data sync to move it to SQL Azure.

Comment: I solved this using the ADF V1 Thanks.